# For loop breaks after one

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach

I have a for loop and it keeps breaking after going around once however I'm unsure on why it is doing this.

```
for (int fX = 1; fX < 17; fX++)
{
    foreach (RoomItem OldItem in Room.GetRoomItemHandler().GetFurniObjects(fX, 26))
    {
        Logging.WriteLine(OldItem.BaseItem.ToString());

        Room.GetRoomItemHandler().RemoveRoomItem(OldItem, false);
    }
}
```

NOTE:
Logging.WriteLine is the same as Console.WriteLine, its just my logging system.

Result of console:

```
1
```

But the console should be outputting (1,2,3 and so fourth)
Any ideas? I even tried locking the foreach iteration but that didn't work.

Comment: Where are you writing to the Console?

Comment: Oh sorry, Logging.WriteLine is writing to the console. Console.WriteLine still displays the same result.

Comment: If GetFurniObjects returns an empty collection, the body of the inner loop is not executed. Can you post the source code of that function?

Comment: Did you try attaching a debugger to it and stepping through? What did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

You modify the collection while you iterate through it. This results in undefined behaviour.

You *may* fix this with using a **constant** list for the `foreach` like so:

```
foreach (RoomItem OldItem in 
    Room.GetRoomItemHandler().GetFurniObjects(fX, 26).ToList())
{
     ...
}
```

But I think you should rather think through your design again.

Comment: I tried locking it but it didn't work, how would I fix this?

Comment: I'd use `ToArray()` while you're not going to add anything to that list.

Comment: Ah, now I remember. Enumeration error. Sorry that slipped out of my head. Thank you!

Comment: ToList() will be actually a bit faster while potentially using more memory, if `Room.GetRoomItemHandler().GetFurniObjects(fX, 26)` returns truly 'IEnumerable'.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be changing a collection while iterating through it using a for-loop, re-write using while or do-while.